# Configure EF Core Context through IOptions

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I have a custom workflow component that uses DI and the .NET Core options pattern, including a connection string to a backing database. I was planning on adding EF Core to do some data access to the same database and would like to use the connection string i am already setting through `services.AddWorkflowEngine()`, however I'm running into issues getting the connection string to EF when internally configuring the DbContext, because the connection strings are not set yet when trying to call `AddDbContext<T>()`.

Is there an appropriate place to setup EF core so the connection string can be set internally through `AddWorkflowEngine()?

**WorkflowEngine.cs**

```
public class WorkflowEngine<TScheme> where TScheme : WorkflowScheme
{
  public WorkflowEngine(IOptions<WorkflowConfigurationOptions<TScheme>> options)
  {
     this.connectionString = options.ConnectionString;
  }
}
```

**Extensions.cs**

```
public static IServiceCollection AddWorkflowEngine<TScheme>(this IServiceCollection services, 
                   Action<WorkflowConfigurationOptions<TWorkflowScheme>> optionsAction) 
                   where TScheme : WorkflowScheme
{
  service.TryAddScoped<WorkflowEngine<TScheme>>();
  services.Configure(optionsAction);
  return services;
}
```

Comment: You don't need IOptions. You can configure the context when you use `AddDbContext` in Startup

Comment: The generic nature of the `WorkflowConfigurationOptions` will make it difficult to use it with the `AddDbContext` overload that would have allowed you to resolve the `IOption` in a deferred configuration delegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @Nkosi's comment, if I wanted to accomplish this, I would have to genericize my `DbContext` in order to inject a `IOptions<WorkflowConfigurationOptions<T>>`, which would introduce too much complexity at this time.

I ended up manually invoking the delegate.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddWorkflowEngine<TScheme>(this IServiceCollection services, 
                   Action<WorkflowConfigurationOptions<TWorkflowScheme>> optionsAction) 
                   where TScheme : WorkflowScheme
{
  service.TryAddScoped<WorkflowEngine<TScheme>>();
  // manually invoke action
  var options = new WorkflowConfigurationOptions<TScheme>();
  optionsAction.Invoke(options);
  services.AddDbContext<WorkflowDbContext>(dbOptions=> 
                dbOptions.UseSqlServer(options.ConnectionString);

  services.Configure(optionsAction);
  return services;
}
```